# In what century did people start using the word "profession"?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, words

I need to find out in what century the word "profession" appeared.

My final goal: to understand whether this word could be used in the Middle Ages in everyday communication, in the meaning that we now understand by this word?

What source of information should I use for this?

This word is missing from The Oxford Dictionary of Word Origins.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question lacks basic research, in this case an OED lookup.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica can you suggest a search source? I am ready to independently find the answer to the question, but searching in dictionaries did not help me. And search engines do not provide the necessary sources of information.

Comment: OED spells out as "Oxford English Dictionary". Locate a copy or an electronic access point and look it up.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I looked in The Oxford Dictionary of Word Origins, but found only:
"..., profane, profound, ..."

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199547920.001.0001/acref-9780199547920?btog=chap&hide=true&page=196&pageSize=20&skipEditions=true&sort=titlesort&source=%2F10.1093%2Facref%2F9780199547920.001.0001%2Facref-9780199547920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) is  a specific dictionary, older and larger than any of the other dictionaries which the Oxford University Press publish. It is available online at https://www.oed.com, but requires a subscription. (In the UK, people can use their public library's subscription: I don't know whether something like that is available anywhere else).

Every entry is provided with a number of dated examples of use, including the oldest example that their researchers have found.

The oldest use of *profession* in the modern sense that they have is from 1425. It is older in other senses (religious conviction etc).

Comment: M-W is available for free and also gives the first usage information, albeit it may not be in the modern sense (it says *"13th century"* for the religious sense) .